# December 2013 SharePoint Public Update

Tags: 2013, cumulative-update

In the past, SharePoint updates have been simple enough to understand:
- RTM gets released
- Cumulative updates get released on an regular schedule
- Service Pack(s) are released, rolling up the cumulative updates
- Further CUs are released that require the previous SP

And after each of those updates, you were required to re-run the configuration wizard.

However, with 2013, I'm seeing a new "Public Update" type of update. The one back in March 2013 was relatively straight forward, and well documented (Still run config wizard, later CUs require the PU to be installed). However, the new one from December 2013 Public Update seems to be very poorly documented.

1. I can't tell what's actually fixed in this update, the only
   description being "This update provides the latest fixes for
   SharePoint Server 2013. It also includes stability and performance
   improvements."
2. Does it require any previous CUs to be installed?
3. Will future CUs require it to be installed?
4. There's 11 different updates included as a part of this. Do I need
   to install each one individually? What about the Project Server
   update that's there?
5. Do I need to re-run the configuration wizard once the install of
   this update is complete?
6. Why was KB2826037 released via Windows Update when no previous
   SharePoint update was made available this way?

Anyone have any answers to these questions?

Comment: There's a December 2013 PU (for SharePoint 2013)? Where??
[http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/]http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft releases the Public Updates almost every month for the Office Products. Mostly these Updates contain the security updates and Non-Security (to improve the performance of the application.). Our TAM, every month these bulletin to us. One thing keep in mind, SharePoint is not the affected party in every months PU. I noticed couple of security updates applied via windows updates as well.

1. I can't tell what's actually fixed in this update, the only description being "This update provides the latest fixes for SharePoint Server 2013. It also includes stability and performance improvements."

> You should check the Office Updates Blog which mentioned all the KB
>   article and each article listed the issue which fixed. Check this link
>   i.e

[December 2013 Office Update Release](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_sustained_engineering/archive/2013/12/09/december-2013-office-update-release.aspx)

Here is the Blog where they post it every month.
[Office Updates](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_sustained_engineering/?pi47604=1)

1. Does it require any previous CUs to be installed?

> Its depend, if it then MSFT mention in the KB. But right now for any
>   updates for 2013 base line is March PU.

1. Will future CUs require it to be installed?

> So far Only March Pu 2013 is requirement for the CU.

1. There's 11 different updates included as a part of this. Do I need to install each one individually? What about the Project Server update that's there?

> If you really need those then apply individual hot fix

1. Do I need to re-run the configuration wizard once the install of this update is complete?

> If it change the version number then you need to run the config
>   wizard. I remember from my past experience, we applied the One
>   security updates but that did not required Config wizard.

1. Why was KB2826037 released via Windows Update when no previous SharePoint update was made available this way?

> I don’t know why they did this, but couple of security updates they
>   include into the windows update.

Finally, I would recommend you that only apply the HotFix / PU KBs if they fix any of the issue other wise wait for future CUs. These will become part of it. For CUs, you need to run the config wizard. Industry normally recommend that no need to install the CU as well if you don’t have problem rather wait for the Service Pack and apply it.

Comment: Yes, there are Public Updates and those come on odd-numbered months. They're currently not documented well.

Comment: But those become part of following CU, isn't ut?

Comment: Just like the PU contains the previous CU, yes.

Comment: Why down voting a good answer, and not add a comment on it? I think the behavior of down voting and not commenting is bad manors and not helpful for the poster, since he gets no other real feedback. I like this answer +1